# How to read URL params in custom created nodes inside N8N? as it's not recognizing any default browser side JS option to get URL

Tags: server-side-rendering, url-parameters, n8n

I am passing some values in URL of n8n,Which is embeded in apllication via Iframe.

My aim is to get those url parameters when I am using the custom node for some automation purpose.

1. have tried window.location.href but it's not recognising window keyword
2. I have tried
   const url = require('url');

let params = new url.URLSearchParams('token=sjsbjs');

console.log(params.get('token'))

but in this above solution I don't know how to get URL and pass it to URLSearchParams